# jQuery / Dojo, UI / Dijit cross reference?

Tags: jquery, dojo

I concede that this question may fall into the 'discussable' but not 'answerable' category. If so, I do apologize and please mark the question as such.

The question: I've mainly used jQuery and UI for my front-end interaction and AJAX. I need to help on a Dojo project quickly if possible and was wondering if anyone knows of a decent bit of documentation that is written more a a cross-reference with jQuery. For instance, if you use jQuery.UI for tabs, then here's the equivalent in Dojo. If you want to select an object with a specific ID you do this in jQuery, and this in Dojo... etc.

(Come to think of it, that might be a great idea for a web site... a jQuery vs. MooTools vs. Dojo vs. Scriptaculous vs. extjs vs. etc examples...)

Comment: I don't have an answer but I'd love seeing one, hence the +1 -- I'm more familiar with Dojo so I'd prefer it "the other way 'round", but such a site (or book, a la "SQL in a nutshell") would be as valuable to me as, indeed, SQL in a nutshell always is (except for looking up equivalent functionality in different JS frameworks rather than in different SQL engines, of course;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to the concept of a cross-reference I can think of is cheat sheets -- you get a quick overview and samples for basic usage.

Here's a good list of JavaScript library cheat sheets which includes jQuery and Dojo:
http://uksen.com/blog/2009/07/15/popular-javascript-libraries-7-cheat-sheets/

I agree with Alex Martelli, it's a great idea for a website. A sort of JavaScript Library Rosetta Stone :)

Comment: Good idea about using the cheat sheets, Brian. Thanks!

Let me know when you all want to begin building that cross-reference site. ;)